# Is there any way to use pseudo elements on React Native (with Styled Components)?

Tags: react-native, pseudo-element, styled-components

Is Styled Components' pseudo elements really compatible with React Native?? Or just ReactJS?
I tried it and it doesn't work:

```
const StyledTextContent = styled.Text`
    display: flex;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #565656;  

    &::after {
        content: '!!!';
        display: 'flex';
    }
`;
```

Comment: React Native does not support pseudo-elements, so you can not use it.

Comment: Yep i read it somewhere.. Styled Components should mention this on their docs :( Thanks buddy..